# Changing value of the input after append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a template html block with allow me to copy that block when I click on Add button. This is done via `append()`

How to change the value of `name='category[]'` input field after it has been appended?

For example:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
   $('#LinesContainer').append($('#templatePlan').html());
   var getCategory = $("#selectCategory").val();
   // How to put getCategory value into category[] field?
});
```

Select Category and click on + button

```
<div>
  <select id="selectCategory">
      <option value="New">New</option>
      <option value="Old">Old</option>
  </select>
  <input value="+" id="add" type="button"/>
</div>
```

Template Block

```
<div id="templatePlan" style="display:none;">
 <div style='padding: 5px; border: 1px solid white; background-color: #FFA86F;'>
  <select name="selectType[]"> 
       <option>Consumer</option>
       <option>Business</option>
  </select>
  <input name='category[]' type='hidden' value='' />
 </div>
</div>


<div id="LinesContainer"> </div>
```

I am not sure if this is a neat way to implement it, is there alternative better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select it. I'd recommend to use [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for the template instead of `innerHTML`, that will make the selection easier. Otherwise you might have multiple category inputs and have to use that last one.

```
$('#add').click(function() {
   $('#templatePlan').children('div').clone().appendTo('#LinesContainer')
    .find('input name="category[]"').val($("#selectCategory").val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you think of overall implementation design? Or should each appended block should have like index number? So every time I click on Add button, it get the max index and increase by 1. Eg: `category_5` field name

Comment: Nah, an array is fine. jQuery doesn't deal with them elegantly but it's better than unnecessary ids. Only one improvement: Merge the hidden template div with its child div then use `$('#templatePlan').clone().show()…`

Comment: Hmmmm, I am trying to figure out. When I click on a submit button and if there is an error - it will go back to form page but I need to repopulate the appended blocks  with fields data. How can that be done? I am using PHP.

Comment: Don't you have the logic to insert and prepoupulate the template on the serverside for a no-javascript-client already? Just echo the template for each entry and set the `value` and `selected` attributes.

Comment: Yep that what I just done, I just wrap up the html template in a PHP function. I reuse the function to populate it. Not sure if that the best way.

Comment: That's just how it is done. Maybe there are frameworks around to abstract some of the work, but it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //after
     var getCategory = $("#selectCategory").val();

//To set the actual input
    $('input[type="hidden"]').val(getCategory);
//or to update the attribute rather
 $('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name', 'category[' + getCategory + ']');
```